# The arabic version not deployed to Sitecore from JSS App

Tags: jss

I am using Sitecore 10 with JSS and my app is built in Angular. After deploying the app to Sitecore I found that the Arabic version of the pages is not deployed to Sitecore, while the English version imported successfully. Is there any configuration to import the ar.yml files to Sitecore?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the sitecore documentation https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/content-translation you can use this command to deploy other languages:

```
    jss deploy items --language=ar-AE --includeContent --includeDictionary
```